# DNA extraction python

Tags: object-tag

Now, I need to find a way in which Python can find the codon position number 5 of the above code and extract that sequence until position 12 (ATGG**CTTTACCTCGTC**TCACAGGAG). So the output should be something like this:

```
>CCODE1112_5..11
 CTTTACCTCGTC
```

How can I tell python to get the begin value after the first "_" and the end value after ".." so it can do it automatically? ? THANKS!!!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Comment: also http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: You should clarify exactly what you are trying to do; no offense, but the description was somewhat ambiguous, e.g. "codon position number 5", "extract that", etc.

Comment: Also codons can be encoded by more than one unique nucleotide triplet. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table

Comment: can we create a 'gimme-codez-nao' tag?

Comment: Although this simple operation can be achieved with string operations, I'd consider using Biopython's `SeqIO` to interact with fasta sequences, especially if you end up doing more complex operations.

You'll find detailed documentation in the [Tutorial and Cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def extractseq( queryseq , begin=5, end =12):
   queryseq=queryseq.split('\n')#transform the string in a list of lines included in the string

   return queryseq[1][begin-1:end-1]
```

I think this function should work, beware of the index which begin at 0 in python

after written that in your script you just have to call the function subs=extractseq(seq,5,12)

ok sorry so if you want to extract the 5 and the 12 included in the *substring* one way to do that easly is:

```
substring=queryseq.split('\n')[0].split('_')[1].split('...')#extraction of the substring
begin=substring[0]
end = substring[1]
```

Comment: Ok, so in there you specify begin=5, end =12, but how can I tell python to get the begin value after the first "_" and the end value after ".." so it can do it automatically? Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably (sigh) use a regex to extract 5 and 12 from CCODE1112_5..12_ABC.

Then convert the extracted strings to int's.

Then use the int's as indexes in a string slice on the DNA data.

For the regex:

> > > > regex = re.compile(r'^[^*]**(\d+)..(\d+)_.*$')
> > > >         regex.match('CCODE1112_5..12_ABC')
> > > >         
> > > >         match = regex.match('CCODE1112_5..12_ABC')
> > > >         match.group(1)
> > > >         '5'
> > > >         match.group(2)
> > > >         '12'

To convert those to int's, use int(match.group(1)), for example.

Then your indices are 1-based, while python's are 0-based.  Also, python's starting point for a slice is at the value you want, and python's ending point for a slice is one past the value you want. So subtract one from group(1) and leave group(2) alone.

So something like:
substring = dna_data[left_point-1:right_point]